# Is this inequality on Schatten p-norm and diagonal elements true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

Let $A=[a_{ij}]\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ be a matrix with $m\ge n$, and $\Vert A\Vert_p$ be the Schatten p-norm of $A$.

It is known that $\Vert A\Vert_1\ge \sum_i \vert a_{ii}\vert$ and $\Vert A\Vert_2^2=\Vert A\Vert_F^2\ge \sum_i \vert a_{ii}\vert^2$.

Can we show that $\Vert A\Vert_p^p\ge \sum_i \vert a_{ii}\vert^p$ for general $p\ge 1$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true, and is a consequence of the following *majorization* result. Let $d_1,\dots,d_n$ be the main diagonal entries of $A$ ordered so that $|d_1|\ge |d_2| \ge \dots\ge |d_n|$. Also let $\sigma_1\ge \sigma_2 \ge \dots \ge \sigma_n$ be the singular values of $A$. The aforementioned (weak) majorization inequality is
$$
\sum_{j=1}^k |d_j| \le \sum_{j=1}^k \sigma_j\qquad \forall \ k =1,2,\dots,n \tag{1}
$$

Weak majorization implies that 
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n \phi(|d_j|) \le \sum_{j=1}^n \phi(\sigma_j)\tag{2}
$$
for every increasing convex function $\phi$. Taking $\phi(t)=t^p$ and recalling that $\Vert A\Vert_p^p = \sum_{j=1}^n \sigma_j^p$, the result follows.

References for inequality (1):

- Problem 21 of section 3.3 in *Topics in Matrix Analysis* by Horn and Johnson;
- Theorem 2.4 of [Chi-Kwong Li's lecture notes](http://www.math.wm.edu/~ckli/ima/note-1.pdf). Here the result is stated for square matrices, but also includes the more difficult converse direction, describing all the possible combinations  of singular values and diagonal entries.  This is a theorem proved independently by Thompson and Sing in 1970s.

References for inequality (2):

- Section I.3.C of *Inequalities: Theory of Majorization and Its Applications* by Marshall, Olkin, and Arnold, 2nd edition.
- Section 3.17 of *Inequalities* by Hardy, Littlewood, and Polya (they consider strong majorization, which requires equality to hold in (1) when $k=n$; but for increasing $\phi$ the weakly-majorized case reduces to strongly majorized).

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much!